# Folder not found error even though the folder exists in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a piece of code in C# that states if a folder exists or not. In PC, you can specify the location and it will accurately state the existence of the folder. I then made the code run on Android by making an application in Unity. But, if I run it and input a location, it states that the folder does not exist even though it does!
My folder location is like this: Phone storage/DCIM/Camera
Am I doing anything wrong?
My Code:

```
TMP_Text textBox;
string path;
if(Directory.Exists(path))
{textBox.text == "Yes";}
else {textBox.text == "No";}
```

Comment: How should we help if you dont show your code?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Pfinnn wait a minute, I will add.

Comment: Use Windows Explorer and see if you have access to the folder.  VS does not automatically run with ADMIN.  If you are an ADMIN than start VS by right click shortcut and select RUN AS ADMIN.  The c# executable will run with ADMIN automatically.  Just inside VS you have to specify ADMIN.

Comment: @jdweng on android?

Comment: @jdweng I have a problem with an android and unity not with PC and VS

Comment: Is the `path` a full path (from root `/` on Linux or with disk drive in Windows)? When the path is relative, is the relative pats from the *start folder* valid? It is possible that the base folder for the check is not the same as the path of application. e.g. application is `/bin/myApp.exe` but the application was started from (and with base folder) `/users/me/data`. When you will check `MyFolder` it will check `/users/me/data/MyFolder` and not `/bin/MyFolder`.

Comment: @Julo that's not it.....

Comment: `storage/DCIM/Camera` this is not a typical path on android, are you sure it is correct? And since android 10 (API29) you cannot directly access media folders without acquired READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and MediaStore APIs.

Comment: @shingo it was a simplification done by my phone's gallery app. I have found correct one, I'll post the answer here right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [Post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174850/how-do-i-get-the-real-file-path-of-an-image), I found a solution. The path I stated, "Phone storage/DCIM/Camera" was a simplification done by my phone's gallery and the correct technical path should be "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera".
Also, the technically correct path for the sd-card is:
"/sdcard/DCIM/Camera"
If I use this code it says that the folder exists :)